# Intersection of decision problems?

Tags: complexity-theory, np, complexity-classes, closure-properties, co-np

Say we have two problems $\Pi_1\in NP$ and $\Pi_2\in coNP$. Where does $\Pi_1\cap\Pi_2$ live?

Comment: What do you mean by $\Pi_1 \land \Pi_2$? $\{ (x_1, x_2) \mid x_1 \in \Pi_1 \land x_2 \in \Pi_2 \}$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean then $\Pi_1 \cap \Pi_2$ (i.e., set intersection)?

Comment: Given two formulas $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ we have $\exists x:\phi_1(x)=1$ is in $NP$ and $\forall y:\phi_2(y)=0$ is in $coNP$. Where is $\{\exists x:\phi_1(x)=1\}\wedge\{\forall y:\phi_2(y)=0\}$?

Comment: What is $A \land B$ for sets $A, B$ supposed to mean? And what is $\{ \exists x : \phi_1(x) = 1 \}$? Do you mean $\{ \phi_1 \mid \exists x: \phi_1(x) = 1\}$?

Comment: No I just mean where is the conjunction of the two problems. That is all there is to it.

Comment: Oh so conjunction of an $NP$ complete problem $\Pi_1$ with a $coNP$ complete problem $\Pi_2$ is in $NP\cap coNP$. Does not make sense. What is the short certificate for $\Pi_2$ in case the conjunction is accepted by a $NP\cap coNP$ machine and what is the short certificate for $\Pi_1$ in case the conjunction is rejected by a $NP\cap coNP$ machine? So I think my problem is still unclear to you.

Comment: Yes, but what is a "conjunction" of two problems? Problems are nothing more than sets (i.e., formal languages), and the conjunction in set theory is simply the intersection. Then $\Pi_1 \cap \Pi_2 \in \mathsf{P} \cap \mathsf{coNP}$, logically. Either that or we simply do not have the same vocabulary.

Comment: @dkaeae I don't see why $\Pi_1\cap\Pi_2$ should be in $\mathrm{NP}\cap \mathrm{coNP}$ (I assume you typoed in your most recent comment). In fact, I don't even see why it should be in $\mathrm{NP}\cup \mathrm{coNP}$.

Comment: No. As @dkaeae has explained, problems are _sets_ of strings.

Comment: Such languages comprise the first level of the [boolean hierarchy](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:B#bh).

Comment: @Ariel How so? It also says $BH_1 = NP$. However I do not see how the problem is in $NP$. Does $BH_1$ denote first level of hierarchy?

Comment: I think Ariel meant *second* level.

Comment: Yes, my mistake.

Comment: If Q is the complexity class you're looking for, can we define Q as follows?
q∈Q iff "there is a nondeterministic turing machine that accepts exactly all strings in q in polynomial time" ∧ "there is a nondeterministic turing machine that accepts exactly all strings in the complement of q in polynomial time".